# ASPNET.Identity and MVC5

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, c#-5.0, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am trying to build authentication using the new Identity and MVC5 but I would like to "join" a separate **user** table to the registration and manage pages. I have read lots on extending the AspNetUser table, but I am desperate to find how to join a separate table. I don't want to just add fields to the AspNetUser table as this project will be a template for other web site applications and each project has different requirements for user tables, therefore I believe it will be more streamline if I can adapt a separate table rather than constantly changing the AspNetUser table.

Any code samples would be greatly appreciated as I learn better by example than explanation!

Alex

Comment: Code first or Model first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ASP.NET Identity uses EF Code First, you can store your Profile as a separate table by adding a new Code First class and adding it to the DbContext. The following post shows how you can do this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this - I've gotten farther than I had - however while I can see my new fields on my Registration form, when I submit I am getting this error message:

The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.

I don't want code first! I already have a database and the default connection is connecting to it; or it did when I first set up the ASPNET Identity..

Answer (score 1):

@Alex this is what have and it does work for me

This creates a custom user class that inherits from IdentityUser just like ApplicationUser,  It also defines a virtual class that is the associated profile class that gets linked when the user is created in the database. This can be done here as a custom solution, to make it so that it uses existing tables, you simply replace the objects here with your entity object from the database, and use a connection string that points to the correct database.

```
  public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
  {
      public virtual CustomUserProfile CustomUserProfile { get; set; }
  }
  public class CustomUserProfile
  {

    [Key]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return Guid.NewGuid(); }
        private set { value = Id; }
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
   //add more items

}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<CustomUserProfile> CustomUserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the controller I have:

```
 public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<CustomUser>(new UserStore<CustomUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<CustomUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public UserManager<CustomUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

This is going to create a new UserManager object using your custom user that inherits from IdentityUser just like ApplicationUser Does.

And The method for adding a new user has:

```
      var user = new CustomUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
                user.CustomUserProfile = new CitadelUserProfile();
                user.CustomUserProfile.FirstName = model.FirstName;


                var result = UserManager.Create(user, model.Password);
```

If you are still running into problems with the migrations, then you can delete the MDF file and re-run the application and it will recreate the database.

Comment: Thanks for this. Already did that. Am waiting for more info from pranav actually who has reported in another blog that they are working on further documentation for this precise scenario.

Comment: Ad this point, even with AspNet Identity 2.0 its all done codefirst. there is a codeplex project ongoing to make it database first but I am not sure where that stands.